# how to add new individual with arc2 to my owl file?

Tags: php, insert, owl, arc2

i have just begin to work with owl file in arc2. i have a owl file like this;

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#"
xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2"
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:uni="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#"
xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-   ontology-2"/>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#Student1">
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#Student"/>
<studies rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#CS101"/>
<studies rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#M201"/>
<studies rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ozgur/ontologies/2019/9/untitled-ontology-2#M204"/>
<first_name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Josef</first_name>
<last_name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Baker</last_name>
<studentID rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">266814</studentID>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

as you can see i have a "Student1" individual, and i want to add new individual "Student2" and it's properties like studies: "abc" and studies:"def" and first name and last name values. i find a code as shown ;

```
prefix SEMKNOW: <http://sk.owl#>
INSERT INTO <http://localhost/SEMKNOW.owl>{
<http://sk.owl#C-21> rdf:Type SEMKNOW:ConferencePapers;
     SEMKNOW:Title "A semantic knowledge management system for scholarly repositories"; 
}
```

but i couldn't convert my code. if anyone can help me i will be very happy. thanks.

Comment: just put the RDF triples between the curly braces

Comment: Actually i am trying to learn triples at the same time. if anyone can write the full code it will be a guide for me for future studies.

Comment: *"learn triples"* - not sure what this means, you should start again. It's just reading any RDF tutorial, and you're done and able to solve the current task. Any N-Triple or Turtle syntax example will solve your issue.